# Snap Points to the lines within specified offset

Tags: postgis, spatial-adjustment

I have data of points which are within specific distance to roads e.g. 1m. Now i want to snap the points to the nearest lines which lie within specified distance to the lines

[image]

What is the best way to do this. Currently i am using postgis and have tried to make shortest line between point and line, extrapolate the line by the required distance and then snap the point to line end. So far i have not been able to extrapolate line in postgis. Please guide

Comment: Do you mean shift by 2 meters perpendicular to nearest road segment? Can you show the query you have tried so far, please.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the query you've already tried, and details of what happens when you try it.